# Subtract rows by using diff() method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a beginner in Python.
I have this cumulative hourly energy consumption for one day:

```
1  10620  
2  15336  
3  15336  
4  19691  
5  29697  
6  32499  
7  32499  
8  37353  
9  48693  
10 54019  
11 54019  
12 54019  
13 58366  
14 64595  
15 64595  
16 64595  
17 69029  
18 74381  
19 74381  
20 74381  
21 74381  
22 79106  
23 80801  
24 80801
```

What I'm trying to do is getting the hourly energy consumption by subtracting the prior row from the next row by using the `diff()` method but python says `'tuple' object has no attribute 'diff'`

Could please anyone tell me where is the error and how can solve it?

Comment: `diff()` method? What `diff()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided no code, no attempt, no definitions of input data types. So just by reading your question, this is what I understood you want. Let's say you have data for 4 hours (`1,2,3,4`), just subtract the data of hours `1,2,3` denoted by `[0:-1]` from the data of hours `2,3,4` denoted by `[1:]`. You can reshape/zip the result as per your desired output (which is unclear from your question).

```
data = np.array([(1, 10620), 
            (2, 15336),
            (3, 15336),  
            (4, 19691)])
hourly = data[:,1][1:] - data[:,1][0:-1]
print (hourly)
```

**Output**

```
[4716    0 4355]
```

Comment: That's what you wanted, right? The hourly difference

Comment: Put this code in your question with proper formatting